# How do you get data from different properties with different names in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the text from a couple of text inputs and I need to get them in a "while" loop. They have different names and I am asking if you can add different numbers to a string and change the property which is being collected data from.

```
onEvent("next", "click", function(getData) {
  while (i = 0, i <= 10)
  i++;
  array[i] = getProperty("Name1" //here I want to change the property name to Name(+1) so it takes info from a different property every time the loop cycles, "text");
  write [i];
});
```

Comment: There is no `function` keyword in C#

Comment: Sure the tags are correct? This looks more like `javascript` and not `c#`. Can you verify the tags you are using for your question?

Comment: This is not valid C# code. Check `while()` syntax and missing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 0;
string TestString1 = $"Name{num}";
string TestString2 = "Name" + num;
num++;
```

Here are two diffrent ways by having a string with a varible in it. Then you can add it by one if you want or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
onEvent("next", "click", function(getData) {
  while (i = 0, i <= 10)
  i++;
  array[i] = getProperty("name" + i , "text");
  write [i];
});
```

Comment: Please add your question. What is wrong with the code or why it doesn't work.